# Getting "Paths should be to files within project directory" error while deploying Shiny app

Tags: shinyapps

Getting "Paths should be to files within project directory" error while deploying Shiny app. I have used a couple of excel files in my server function, which could be causing the problem. These files are stored in the same directory as my app.R function, and while giving the path in the server function, I have given the complete path starting from C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/R/...... Is this the correct way to do it? How to fix the error?

I have used a couple of excel files in my server function, which could be causing the problem. These files are stored in the same directory as my app.R function, and while giving the path in the server function, I have given the complete path starting from C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/R/...... Is this the correct way to do it? How to fix the error?